# lambda in vb.net: Select certain objects of a list, based on an attribute of a list of object within the first object

Tags: c#, vb.net, lambda

The question's title isn't super clear, but I had a hard time formulating it any better. I'll show an example of what I am trying to do.

```
Function foo(id As Integer) As List(Of Version)

    Dim listOfVersions as List(Of Version) = New List(Of Version)

    For each version In MasterListOfVersions
        For each object In version.ListOfObjects
            If object.idObject = id Then listOfVersions.Add(version)
        Next
    Next

    Return listOfVersions

End Function
```

This works, but I am trying to turn that into a lambda expression. So far, I have this down:

```
Return MasterListOfVersions.Select(Function(version) version.ListOfObjects.Where( _
                                   Function(object) object.idObject = id)).ToList()
```

But it isn't quite right... I get the following error message:

```
List(Of IEnumerable(Of Object)) cannot be converted to List(Of Version)
```

I feel like I'm pretty close to the answer, but I've looked for a while and it seems like I'm stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "it isn't quite right" doesn't give us much information. Does it compile? If not, what's the error? If it does, what does it do wrong?

Comment: You're right Jon, here's the error message:

List(Of System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Object)) cannot be converted to List(Of Version)

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?

Comment: Please edit the error message into the question rather than leaving it in comments - the question should have all the relevant information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you don't need to call `Select` at all - you're only performing a *filtering* operation, which is what `Where` gives you. You're not trying to transform the list. So just use:

```
Return MasterListOfVersions.Where_
    (Function(version) version.ListOfObjects.Any_
        (Function object) object.id = id)).ToList()
```

In other words, return all the versions where *any* of the objects within that version has the specified ID. Note that unlike your original code, this will only add each element of `MasterListOfVersions` once, even its `ListOfObjects` has multiple entries with the matching ID. I suspect this is what you want, to be honest.

Note that in your original code, you're using `object.idObject` in one place but `object.id` in another. It's not obvious which is correct.

Comment: The version doesn't have the id I'm looking for. The version has a list of Objects, which has an id attribute. That's what I'm filtering on.

Comment: @Felix So then change it to `version.Lists.Any(Function(obj) obj.id = id)` or whatever the VB syntax is for that.

Comment: @Felix: Ah, right, sorry, I hadn't understood properly. Fixing as per emodendroket's suggestion, which is basically the right approach :)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use .SelectMany to select from the child list.

I have a blog post about it here:
http://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/finding-in-a-child-list/

Here is an example from that post:

```
Dim foundCustomers = custList. 
    SelectMany(Function(cust) cust.ContactList. 
        Where(Function(cn) cn.LastName.StartsWith("B")), 
                Function(cust, cn) cust)
```

Comment: But then you can't get back the original (parent) item.  What you really want is `.Where(ver => ver.ListOfObjects.Any(o => o.Id == id))`.

Comment: Actually, maybe that's not what you want; I can't tell what the OP is asking.  If you just want the child entities then this is fine.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. I want the original item, so a list of "version" in my example. If you want to type that out as an answer I think I'll accept it because it looks like it's working.